# Build a Corpus with smaller corpuses texts as variable in Quantida

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda

I am a beginner r user and I would need some help with my project.

I want to build a quantida corpus for text analysis. I have scraped webpages from a number of website and thus obtained a dataframe for each site. What I am trying to do is to analyse the textual data. I am interested in knowing the overall content of these webpages, but I would also like to have the single website as variable that I can select since I want to see if there are any significant variation at this level. I have tried to assign a different label to every site corpus and then merge them:

**corp_site1<-corpus(dataframe_site1$txt, meta= "site1")**

**corp_site2<-corpus(dataframe_site2$txt, meta= "site2")**

**corp_site3<-corpus(dataframe_site3$txt, meta= "site3")**

**corp_tot<-corp_site1+corp_site2+corp_site3**

When I try to execute the last code I get the following error message:

***Error: Cannot combine corpora with duplicated document names***

I am not sure what this message means (I tried to look it up on google and could not find anything) and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I also took a look at docnames and docvars and they cannot be used in my case as I have no dataframe level elements that define the sitename.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have three corpus objects each with one document with the same name.  In **quanteda**, docnames must be unique.

The other problem is that you are trying to assign the website name as "metadata", which is specific to the corpus, not to each document.  (Corpus metadata also needs to be in the format of a named list.)

A better way to do this is to combine the data before you construct the corpus.  If the non-textual data is in the data.frame, it will automatically be imported as a "docvar" or document-level metadata field.  Below, I've shown an example using some sample data matching the structure of your scraped data.frame objects.

```r
# create sample data
data_frame_site1 <- data.frame(
  txt = "This is website one.",
  meta = "site1"
)
data_frame_site2 <- data.frame(
  txt = "This is website two.",
  meta = "site2"
)
data_frame_site3 <- data.frame(
  txt = "This is website three.",
  meta = "site3"
)
```

Now let's create a single object.  I've done this to combine all data objects named `data_frame_*` here since you may find it more convenient, if you have many such objects.

```r
# puts all of your objects into one data.frame
all_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ls(pattern = "^data_frame_"), get))
all_df
##                      txt  meta
## 1   This is website one. site1
## 2   This is website two. site2
## 3 This is website three. site3
```

Make the corpus is now easy and it will automatically import your `meta` column as a document variable.

```r
# now make the corpus
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

corp <- corpus(all_df, text_field = "txt")
corp
## Corpus consisting of 3 documents and 1 docvar.
## text1 :
## "This is website one."
## 
## text2 :
## "This is website two."
## 
## text3 :
## "This is website three."
summary(corp)
## Corpus consisting of 3 documents, showing 3 documents:
## 
##   Text Types Tokens Sentences  meta
##  text1     5      5         1 site1
##  text2     5      5         1 site2
##  text3     5      5         1 site3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I fully understand what I was doing wrong. I have followed your example and I successfully managed to merge two of my dataframes with site metadata in one corpus. It will be a lot of work to convert all my dataframes to this format but the code you posted will make it faster. I also have to thank you as I did not know about such shortcuts like using do.call to merge my dataframes into one!

Comment: Glad to help. The lapply in the do.call is designed to make a list of your objects, so if you think about scraping each page into a list, you won't need to construct this list as I have here.